# Stop time interval service on logout

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working with angular js. I have created one controller function and call it countinuously so set timeinterval. And I have to run globally so created service for it. For example :

Here below is **NotificationController** :

```
app.controller('NotificationController', function($scope, $http, notificationService, $interval) {
    $interval(function() {
        notificationService.userNotification().then(function(response){
           $scope.notification = response.data.notification;
           $scope.total_notifcation = $scope.notification.length;
        });
    },5000);

    this.update_notification = function(notification_id,index) {
        var is_read_data = $.param({notification_id:notification_id});

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: apiUrl + "tickets/update_notification",
            data: is_read_data,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            }
        }).then(function(response) {
            $scope.notification.splice(index,1);
            $scope.total_notifcation = $scope.notification.length;
        });
    }
});
```

Here below is **notificationService** :

```
app.service("notificationService",function($http,$q,$window) {
    this.userNotification = function() {
        return $http({
            method:"GET",
            url:apiUrl + "tickets/notification"
        });
    }
})
```

Now in **authController** there is a logout function that looks like below :

```
vm.logout = function() {
    if($window.sessionStorage.getItem('userInfo'))
    {
        $window.sessionStorage.clear();
        $state.go('login');
    }
}
```

Here,after logout this service call continuously. When I refresh page than it stop. But I want to stop it when I call **logout**. So what should I have to do to stop it?

Comment: Where is your NotificationController getting used? Is it active all the time? Because you are not starting interval in the service. It is in the controller. When is the NotificationController unloaded?

Comment: @Shahzad yes, after login it is active all time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your NotificationController, save the promise returned by the interval.

```
var interval = $interval(function() {
    notificationService.userNotification().then(function(response){
       $scope.notification = response.data.notification;
       $scope.total_notifcation = $scope.notification.length;
    });
},5000);
```

When the controller is destroyed, cancel the interval.

```
$scope.$on("$destroy", function () {
    $interval.cancel(interval);
})
```

In case your controller never gets unloaded, even on logout, you can save the interval reference in $rootScope like this:

```
$rootScope.notificationInterval = $interval(function() {
notificationService.userNotification().then(function(response){
   $scope.notification = response.data.notification;
   $scope.total_notifcation = $scope.notification.length;
  });
},5000);
```

and stop interval on logout

```
vm.logout = function() {
  if($window.sessionStorage.getItem('userInfo'))
  {
      $window.sessionStorage.clear();
      $rootScope.notificationInterval.cancel();
      $state.go('login');
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `$destroy` ? and this function is not working. And still it call service continuously.

Comment: @NisargBhavsar Does your controller gets unloaded on logout? $destroy is an event fired when the controller unloads and gets destroyed. This can be used for cleanups.

Comment: Yes, after logout notification controller is unloaded.

Comment: @NisargBhavsar If the controller is unloaded, destroy function should definitely be called. Put a console.log or alert to verify. I have also updated the answer with an alternate approach.

Comment: I have put debugger on destroy function it call when called `logout` function.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I have change code in destroy function and it is solved.

Answer (score 1):

$interval returns a promise. Assign this promise to a variable and pass it through any shared service from your **NotificationController** to **authController**

```
var promise = $interval(function() {
    notificationService.userNotification().then(function(response){
       $scope.notification = response.data.notification;
       $scope.total_notifcation = $scope.notification.length;
    });
},5000);

sharedService.currentIntervalPromise = promise;
```

Now from **authController** fetch the promise from shared service and cancel it within logout function.

```
vm.logout = function() {
  var promise = sharedService.currentIntervalPromise;
  if($window.sessionStorage.getItem('userInfo'))
  {
      $interval.cancel(promise);
      $window.sessionStorage.clear();
      $state.go('login');
  }
}
```

Comment: It gives an error like sharedService is not defined.

Comment: You have to write a custom service (here I mentioned sharedService) that can be used for passing data from one controller to another (like your **notificationService**)

Comment: Yes, I have use `notificationService` and try it but its not working.

Comment: Have you injected **notificationService** in **authController**? Can you share your updated code or a **fiddle**?

Comment: Yes, I have injected in **authController**.